# Crystal Reports 2013 Doesn't apply filter

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a project developed in VS2008 and i'm migrating to vs2013. Everythings ok but i've noticed that all of my crystal reports doesn't apply the filters using the parameters passed.

For instance, this is the selection in the crystal report:

[image]

And i'm passing parameters this way:

```
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

    Dim CR As New ReportDocument
    Dim CRParams As New ParameterFields
    Dim CRParam As New ParameterField

    CR.Load("infVolumenVenta2.rpt", OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByDefault)

    ' Creamos la conexion
    Dim CRTableLogoInfos As New TableLogOnInfos
    Dim CRTableLogoInfo As New TableLogOnInfo
    Dim CRConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo

    CR.SetDatabaseLogon("<user>", "<password>")
    CR.ParameterFields("desde").CurrentValues.AddValue(CDate(txtDesde.Text))
    CR.ParameterFields("hasta").CurrentValues.AddValue(CDate(txtHasta.Text))
    CR.ParameterFields("idTienda").CurrentValues.AddValue(cmbTiendas.SelectedValue)
```

The Report shows: 
[image]

The three fields at top are the value of the parameters i've passed before. But doesn't matter the dates i pass. Always shows the same report, the filter is not applying.

The same code and report in VS2008 works fine.

Do i have to change something to work with CR in VS2013?